# PGFPlots: Centering axis lines with outside tick labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

**What I am trying to achieve:**

Basically I want to get as close to this picture as possible:
[image: Picture of an empty diagram with centered axis lines but labels on the outside]

Note that the axis lines are centered but that the tick labels are on the outside (similar to the boxed axis style).

**What I have so far:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % For \resizebox
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=center,
                grid=major,
                xlabel=\(x\), xmin=-5.25, xmax=5.25,
                xtick distance=1, xtick pos=bottom,
                ymin=-5.25, ymax=5.25,
                ytick distance=1, ytick pos=left,
            ]

            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
     } % \resizebox
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of an empty diagram with centered axis lines with labels directly on the axes]

As you can see the ticks themselves were indeed moved to left and bottom  as specified by `xticklabel pos=bottom` and `yticklabel pos=left`.

Note that, according to the [PGFPlots manual Revision 1.16](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), section 4.15.2 (*Tick Alignment: Positions and Shifts*):

> Changing `tick pos` will also affect the placement of tick labels.

However, this does not seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I show one possible solution to achieve what you want.

The quoted text in your question is maybe a bit misleading, but it is also written there, that this only affects *boxed plots*.

Nevertheless, have a look at the comments in the code to get further information.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        xmin=-5.25,
        xmax=5.25,
        ymin=-5.25,
        ymax=5.25,
        xlabel=$x$,
        % move the `xlabel` to the right of the arrow
        xlabel style={
            anchor=west,
        },
        xtick distance=1,
        xtick pos=bottom,
        ytick distance=1,
        ytick pos=left,
        grid=major,
        % -----------------------------
        % move ticklabels to the "outside"
        xticklabel style={
%            % hard-coded solution --> dependent of axis scaling/size
%            yshift=-82pt,
            % relative shifting --> independent of axis scaling/size
            shift={(0,0 |- {axis description cs:0,-1})}
        },
        yticklabel style={
%            % hard-coded solution --> dependent of axis scaling/size
%            xshift=-100pt,
            % relative shifting --> independent of axis scaling/size
            shift={(0,0 -| {axis description cs:-0.53,0})}
        },
        % remove the ticks themselves
        % (which are moved as well)
        tickwidth=0pt,
        % show the "0"s (zeros) again
        hide obscured x ticks=false,
        hide obscured y ticks=false,
        % -----------------------------
%        % for testing only to see, if the shifting works independent of
%        % axis scaling
%        height=10cm,
    ]

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you, this looks very good. I am however surprised there is no pre-defined option in PGFPlots to do this.

Comment: Nice answer! I believe you can improve it by not hard-coding the shifts, e.g., `xticklabel style={shift={(0,0 |- current axis.south of origin)}}`.

Comment: @Emma, that was a great idea but unfortunately "outer" anchors cannot be used *inside* the `axis` environment, because at that time they are not defined. But the `axis description cs` is and thus, one can use this to relatively shift the `ticklabels` and thus the solution works independent of the `axis` size/scaling. Many thanks for that hint! I adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Huh, for some reason using `current axis` got the desired result for me, even though it compiled with errors (which I didn't notice). Using `axis description cs` is clearly better. Better still I think would be to use `xticklabel* cs` for the y tick labels and `yticklabel* cs` for the x labels, to avoid the pesky -0.53.